# Why this code is not re-prompting correctly?

Tags: c, while-loop

I am totally new to C.
I want to re-prompt when the input value is not a number and when it's a number it should be less than 1.  when I give any sort of string it works correctly. But when I give any number it goes to the next line without printing "Number: ".Then in the next line, it prints "Number: "again if the input value is less than 1.

```
int x;
printf("Number: ");
while (scanf("%d", &x) != 1 || x < 1 )
{

    printf("Number: ");

    scanf("%*s");
}
```

and the result it gives me is this

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlNJg.png)

Comment: "I want to re-prompt when the input value is not a number and is less than 1": what do you mean by "and is less than 1"? Why will you check if a string is "less than 1"? Do you mean "or the number is less than 1"?

Comment: The `scanf("%*s")` call won't work as expected in all cases. My suggestion is that you read *lines* (with e.g. [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)) instead, and then use `sscanf` to parse the input.

Comment: My advice is to stop mucking about with simple user input and just use a tried and tested method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-do-i-read-a-string-entered-by-the-user-in-c/4023921#4023921. Once you've got the line, you can then use `sscanf` to check and retry.

Comment: Did you try to compile your code with a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` ? You could get warnings, and improve your C code to get none of them! Once your code has no warnings, use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger to understand its behavior.

Comment: The easiest fix would be to change `scanf("%*s");` -> `scanf("%*[^\n]");` but you should really avoid this and learn how to use fgets+sscanf.

Answer (score 1):

It would be wise to use `fgets` to read the line, then use `sscanf` to parse the input. That way, you can get the line, then check if `sscanf` succeeds!
Simple example:

```c
int target_number; // The number you will have at the end of this.
while (1) { // Loop for rechecking number
    char line[16]; // See notes on how to read the whole line.
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);

    // We use 1 here because sscanf returns the number of format specifiers that are matched. Since you only need one number, we use 1.
    if (sscanf(line, "%d", &target_number) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid Input! Please enter in a valid number.");
        continue;
    }
}

// Do whatever you will with target_number
```

### Notes

You can see how to read the whole line [here](https://people.cs.uchicago.edu/%7Edmfranklin/tutorials/fgets.txt).

#### This code is not safe!

It does not protect against buffer overflow attacks and the like. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-do-i-read-a-string-entered-by-the-user-in-c/4023921#4023921) on the right way to do this. If this is just for learning, you don't need to worry.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*This is how it will work the way you want. 
If I understand  your goal correctly, of course? 
If your goal was different, 
please specify and I will try to solve it.*/



#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
int x;
printf("Number: "); 
while (scanf("%d.%*d", &x)!=1 || x<0) 
{
if(x<0)
{
printf("Number: ");
continue;
}
else
printf("Number: ");
scanf("%*s");
}
printf("Hello world!");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: My goal is to ask for input again and again until I give it a number that is more than 0. That number can be a float also.  For example, if I input a string then it will again ask for input. If I input a negative number then it will ask for input again. But if I input any positive int/float number then it will go for the rest of the code.

Comment: I changed my code. Check it out. If this is what you wanted, I will be glad.

Comment: Your code didn't work as it should because the conditions that you specified in while ( ) are at different levels of perception for the compiler. Therefore, the condition x<0 must be handled separately.

Comment: Brother this code works fine but when a negative fractional number is given as input it doesnt work.

Comment: Well, then that's it. Check it out. Just what you need. Look, I changed the code a little.

Comment: Secret ingredient.)))

Comment: Bro in this updated code if I input anything like (-0.2,-0.4,-0.83) it executes the rest of the code. But I want to re-prompt for input in this case too.

Comment: I think we should listen to our older comrades.